# php custom link and custom pages

Tags: php, html

I was looking on google and couldn't find anything useful.

Basically, I need to make an html/php-based marketplace but I'm stuck on 1 thing. I want to have a custom link like   domain.com/store/tshirt.

What I mean is that I want to generate a custom page with a custom link like wordpress has, without making new html/php pages for each product, because it would take a lot of space and time to do it.

So basically, what I'm looking for is a way to generate custom pages with custom links using data from the database, which is inserted from admin-panel like wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is using rewrite rules in an `.htaccess` file.

It takes a few steps to do.

1. Create an `.htaccess` file if you don't already have one.
2. Create your rewrite rule
3. Change the links on your page to match the new rewrite rule.
4. Change your sql query

**Example:**

You have a link to a page like this... `example.com/products.php?id=24`

You want your URL to look like this... `example.com/belgian-coffee`

Step 1) make your rewrite rule in `.htaccess` like this...

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$    products.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle page requests`
```

Step 2) change the link from `<a href="/products.php?id=24">Belgian Coffee</a>` to `<a href="/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $row['ProductName']) ?>">Belgian Coffee</a>`
Note: The `str_replace` function will replace any spaces in your product name to hyphens

Step 3) Before you query the database for the product name "reverse engineer" your passed parameter. In this case... `belgian-coffee` like this...

```
$productname = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['id'])
```

Step 4) Change your sql statement to query for the product name instead of the product ID

All done!

**Reference**

[htaccess manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
[htaccess guide](http://htaccess-guide.com/)

Comment: awesome solution, finally I could do it.

Answer (score 0):

for this you could follow a MVC architecture in php so that u could use a custom link for custom pages to learn mvc YOU can follow this 
[tutorial](http://jream.com/lab)
else you could use .HTACCESS