# Change URL of previous posts and next posts link in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, get

I'd like to change the URL of the `<?php previous_posts_link ?>` and `<?php next_posts_link ?>` that are being outputted by *Wordpress*.

**Problem:**

> When I am on my single page, I am getting this kind of an url:
>
> http://example.com/post-title/2/

**What I like to achieve:**

> When I am on my single page, I would like to get:
>
> http://example.com/2/

**So, the URL without the post title!**

I don't know if this is even possible, but I'd like to understand if this is doable or not.

Could someone help me out here, please?

Comment: Nobody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Get next/previous post object using `get_previous_post()` & `get_next_post()` and build your custom url.

Comment: Great, but how? Any link/source?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom URLs for your pages within the .htaccess file. I found a useful link that might be able to help you out from another thread. [php custom link and custom pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548841/php-custom-link-and-custom-pages)